# How to convert a date of integers to a formated date string (i.e. 2012009 to 2/01/2009)

Tags: c#, string, datetime, date

Any ideas?
I can't come up with any.

I have a list of dates I'm loading in from a csv file and they are saved as all integers, or rather a string of integers (i.e. Jan 1, 2009 = 1012009)

Any ideas on how to turn 1012009 into 1/01/2009?

Thanks!

Comment: Pay attention to leading zeros.

Comment: Is that `Mddyyyy`, or `dMMyyyy`? January 1st doesn't help much `:)`

Comment: Format is both MMddyyyy and Mddyyyy.  I marked the other answer as THE answer because it worked best for me. This one might work just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int date = 1012009;

var month = date / 1000000;
var day = (date / 10000) % 100;
var year = date % 10000;

var formatted = new DateTime(year, month, day).ToString();
```

This assumes month-day-year; if the numbers are day-month-year, I’m sure you’ll be able to swap the month and day variables to accommodate that.

If you want to customise the date format, you can do so as described in:

- **[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)**
- **[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)**

Comment: I actually wouldn't take it as an integer when it is read from an csv (text) and formatted like a date without separators. I would directly parse it from the string.

Answer (score 6):

Since the date is stored as a string, you may want to use [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("28012009", "dMMyyyy", null);
```

`ParseExact` will throw an exception if the format doesn't match. It has other overloads, where you can specify more than a single possible format, if that is required. Note that here `provider` is `null`, which uses the current culture.
Depending on style you may wish to use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Let 10102009 be dateInt.

```
string dateString = dateInt.ToString();
int l = dateString.Length;
dateString = dateString.Insert(l-3,"/");
dateString = dateString.Insert(l-6,"/");
```

You should now have 1/01/2009 in dateString.. You can also try the [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) function..

Comment: Discarding the result of `Insert`.

Comment: still isn't hot - `dateString` is an `int`, and `l` should be an `int`. It is generally better to run the code first, make sure it works.