# Turning an integer string date into an actual date

Tags: string, r, date, integer, format

I'm trying to turn a date in the format of 01102013 (1st of October 2013), say, into an actual
R date.

I found a similar question relating to C# but no solutions for R.

[How to convert a date of integers to a formated date string (i.e. 2012009 to 2/01/2009)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553734/how-to-convert-a-date-of-integers-to-a-formated-date-string-i-e-2012009-to-2-0)

I tried the obvious way of `as.Date(date, format=%d%m%Y)` but it came up with the error that
the origin was missing (since it is reading the integer as a number of days since a date but it is the actual date just without dashes or slashes in between).

I also tried to find a way of inserting - or \ between the numbers to try and get R to 
recognise it but I can't find a way to do that either.

Comment: Also could try: `date <- 01102013`; `lubridate::dmy(date)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lubridate does this for you:

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(01102013)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to parse it as a character string, you need to convert it to character first. You also need to put quotes around the format string.

```
> date <- 01102013
> date
# [1] 1102013
# you need leading zeros, so you can't just use as.character()
> as.Date(sprintf("%08d", date), format="%d%m%Y")
# [1] "2013-10-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

@JoshuaUlrich's answer is good, but to answer your other question ("how do I insert separators between the parts of the date?") ...  (you still need make sure you do the zero-padding when converting from numeric to character, as Josh shows)

```
cdate <- sprintf("%08d",date)
datestr <- paste(substr(cdate,1,2),
         substr(cdate,3,4),substr(cdate,5,8),sep="/")

as.Date(datestr,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```