# Turning an actual date into an integer value in R

Tags: r, date, integer

Using R, I want to be able to turn a date in format "2014-12-31" to an integer of 20141231, for the purpose of creating a serial number.

My aim is simply to be able to complete the REVERSE of this user question ([Turning an integer string date into an actual date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117112/turning-an-integer-string-date-into-an-actual-date)).

Appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply format the Date in that way, then call `as.integer` on the result.

```
R> as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m%d"))
[1] 20151008
```

---

If your date isn't a Date, and is a character string: either convert it to a Date first, or remove the `"-"` before calling `as.integer`.

```
R> dateString <- "2014-12-31"
R> as.integer(format(as.Date(dateString), "%Y%m%d"))
[1] 20141231
R> as.integer(gsub("-", "", dateString))
[1] 20141231
```

Comment: Thank you for a swift reply @joshua-ulrich.  In attempting to use this solution I receive the following error: 

`> as.integer(format(testdate, "%Y%m%d"))
Error in format.default(testdate, "%Y%m%d") : invalid 'trim' argument`

Comment: @Qaribbean Your "date" is not a `Date` variable. Either use `as.Date` or the suggestion in the other answer.

Comment: @Qaribbean: You said you had a date, so I assumed it was a Date object. Apparently, it's just a character string.

Comment: @joshua-ulrich My apologies for not clarifying.

Comment: @joshua-ulrich Thank you for that updated answer, this is also helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Or if you already have character dates:

```
a <- "2015-03-15"
as.integer(gsub(pattern = "-", replacement="", x = a))
#[1] 20150315
```